# Securing Geoserver layers, displaying in Openlayers 3

Tags: php, authentication, openlayers-3, geoserver

I have a Geoserver instance which serves my spatial data in WFS / WMS / WMTS formats that I then use within an Openlayers 3 application.

What I am now looking at is introducing authentication but I am struggling to work out the best way of doing it.

I want to be able to use my data within my OL3 applcation, but impost authentication if anyone wishes to access the data via desktop software such as QGIS.

Is the only approach I can take to introduce authentication on Geoserver, and then enable the layers to be used in OL3 through authenticating them? How would this be achieved?

I am thinking that PHP can be used here which would hold the username and password, that can then be passed to OL3 when a layer is requested?

This is a theoretical question and would like some advice on the best approach to take for this scenario.

Thanks